# Не формируется массив почему?

Tags: php, массивы

Здравствуйте!

Есть код

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Ошибка соединения с БД: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('reestr', $link) or die ('Ошибка в выборе БД : ' . mysql_error());

$blankid = $_POST['blankid'];
$blankdate = $_POST['blankdate'];
$query = "SELECT 'blank_id' FROM `blanki`";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if($id_array = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)){
echo $id_array;
}
else echo "shit";
?>
```

почему выводит просто слово Array,без данных в массиве?

Comment: <?php

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Ошибка соединения с БД: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('reestr', $link) or die ('Ошибка в выборе БД : ' . mysql_error());

$blankid = $_POST['blankid'];
$blankdate = $_POST['blankdate'];
$query = "SELECT 'blank_id' FROM `blanki`";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if($id_array = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)){
echo $id_array;
}
else echo "shit";
?>

Comment: Вы где видели чтоб массив выводили с помощью оператора `echo`.для этого есть специальные операторы `prin_r($id_array)`,`var_dump($id_array)`

Answer (score 2):

`print_r($id_array)` так как на выходе содержится массив,если вы уже хотите обратится к конкретному индексу массива используйте echo `$id_array['индекс']`.Плюс удобнее использовать `mysql_fetch_assoc()`вместо`fetch_array()`

Answer (score 0):

Если массив одномерный, попробуйте выводить данные про элементы массива так:

```
foreach ($id_array as $key => $var) {
    echo $key." => ".$var."<br>";
}
```